# How to use PS3 Game Controller in OS X?

Tags: macos, open-source, hardware

I am trying to set up PowerA Mini Pro game controller in OS X El Capitan. 
However, I have not succeeded via USB. It would be great if there is some central settings for the customization of each button. 
I need the gamepad for data visualization only, not for actual gaming. 
There are a lot third-party control apps but I would like to find some major app.
Open-source application is the best choice, because in case of random errors, I could be sure that the conntroller itself is not causing it. 
So I am not confident about the application *Joystick Mapper by Chibata Creations*.

I choose the PowerA mini Pro controller because of analog buttons and joystics. 
I need the analog control. 
I choose PS3 because it is widely supported and has sufficient userbase. 
Systems

- scientific computation etc Matlab - none
- for gaming, [openemu.org](http://openemu.org/)

where I think openemu.org has best drivers. It would be great to have such drivers system wide such that you could use them for scientific computation and visualization.

---

How can you set up a PS3 game controller in OS X El Capitan?

Comment: That would probably depend a lot on what you intended to use the PS3 controller for.

Comment: @RedEagle2000 Please, see my edit of the body.

Comment: Something like http://osxdaily.com/2014/12/28/connect-playstation-3-controller-mac-os-x/ maybe?